# Reboot Emachines D620 (Vista) to factory default without using alt + f10 partition

Tags: windows-vista, reboot, emachines

I recently have had my computer repaired as it had hardware problems and it was working fine but for some reason it has started being unresponsive and extremely slow. I decided to try to reboot the computer but when I went on the start menu to use the Emachines recovey management  (the laptop does not come with recovery disks) it was not there and it seems that it was not reinstalled after being repaired. I searched for  a recovery partition and I found that Alt+F10 usually works for emachines computers, however when I do this it comes up with an Edit Boot Options screen with this message:
Partition: 2 
Hard Disk: b8f0ffa4 
[ /NOEXECUTE=OPTIN        ] 
I have read that I need to enable Disk to disk boot in the BIOS menu but there is no such option in my BIOS menu and i cannot find another way to reboot the laptop.
I have even tried to copy the program files for the emachines recovery management from my sister's laptop which is the same as mine but every time I try to open it, it doesn't respond and closes the program.
Is there any other way for me to reboot the laptop?

Comment: Do you have any CDs that came with the laptop? Not all laptops come with a recovery partition, and it looks like this model may be lacking it.